# A bug in leagues?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I just went to this page: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

And it shows this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/123387/justin-van-horne as top for this week with 758 points of reputation for this week.

However, it wasn't active for a long time and didn't get any reputation in this week at all.

Comment: Must be Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation league thing is probably just a caching issue, because he just lost points for a deleted question.  He gained +758 points on [an answer migrated yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858895/1288), but then subsequently deleted it.

The answer was on [Why does this PNG image display differently in Chrome & Firefox than in Safari and IE?](https://superuser.com/q/579216/1170), which looks like it got bounced from SU then back.